# How to pre-define different symbology for a all features of a geopackage?

Tags: qgis

I have a geopackage for a list of invasive plant species. There are hundreds of plants and I want to apply a different predefined colour to each. I cannot find a way to do this without drawing every single plant on the map first. I have tried organising by categorized, but when I click classify it just says "all other values" instead of listing each species and applying a different colour.

If it is possible to quickly do that, then I also want to give different plants different symbology based on their impact. There are 3 levels - low, medium and high. I want Low impact plants to be circles, medium to be squares and high to be triangles. Can anyone help me with some rules or tell me the a string that would list all plants?

I have all plants listed under "Common Name" and each has a different field value rating under "Impact" that varies depending on the plant. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want "Common name" to define the colour and "Impact" to define the shape (triangle, circle or square). To create a QGIS style based on two fields, you can use the "Rule-based" symbology which allows you to define multiple rules for styling based on conditions involving different fields.

Open Layer properties and go to Symbology tab, then choose Rule-based styling from dropdown menu.

Add a new rule by clicking the green "+"-button.

Define rule conditions by clicking the button next to the "Filter" field. In this case it would be a good idea to create three rules per each species: low, medium and high, different shapes but same colour.

String you need is something like  "common name"  = 'apple tree' AND  "impact" = '1' depending on your field names, and then you just define that these features are red circles. Then you add another rule but now the impact value is "2" and styling is a red square etc. Remember to save before you close the menu.

[Styling QGIS Rule-Based](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkwci.png)

I hope this will help!